# Jenkins: 'robot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I'm a begginer with robot framework and I'm trying to run a test on jenkins but I get the following error:

*'robot' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an operable program or a batch file.
Build step 'Run on Windows command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE*

The Jenkins is installed on the same machine as the robot structure, and through the windows command prompt I can normally run the test. Only Jenkins does not identify the robot command. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Please do a search of this site for `is not recognized as an internal or external command*. There are at least 100 existing questions and answers here about how to solve that problem. Always search the site first before asking a new question, as chances are quite good that it's been asked and answered before.

Comment: Hi, Ken White. Thanks for the answer and the recommendation, but I was with the problem for a few days and to ask here before I searched for all possible alternatives I found on the web. I apologize for not being clear about this in my question.
Fortunately an angel youtuber had the patience to give me a direction to conduct my research on how to solve my problem. He simply said: "check the user where the tests are running on Jenkins".
My Jenkins was running with the "nt / system authority" user.

Comment: When I configured the service to run with my Windows user, the robot command was recognized normally (the robot path was already configured on my machine).